# Realizar AutoFill o FillDown en columna filtrada. Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Buenos días,

El problema que tengo es el siguiente. Después de hacer un filtro con criterio distinto a N/A, me sitúo en la primera celda filtrada para realizar un BUSCARV. Esta operación la realiza perfectamente, el problema está en cuanto quiero hacer un Autofill o Filldown el cual lo único que realiza es un cambio de la primera celda a N/A en forma de texto general.

Adjunto el código para su revisión

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$1113").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>#N/A" _
    , Operator:=xlAnd

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Select

 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC10,[Contratos.xls]Feuil1!R2C1:R738C2,2,0)"
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Selection.FillDown
```

¿Alguien sabe cual puede ser el problema?. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes,

Yo lo que haría sería copiar la celda que contiene la fórmula, y luego seleccionar todas las celdas visibles y pegar el pastespecial xlFormulas para que pegue la fórmula en todas las celdas visibles tras el filtro.

```
Sub Testfiltro()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, Col As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'Aquí le decimos a Excel que wb significa este libro
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("NombreHoja") 'Aquí cambia "NombreHoja" por el nombre de la hoja donde harás el filtro

    LastRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row ' Aquí miras cual es la última fila, así cuando la tabla aumente de tamaño filtra todo
    Col = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column 'Lo mismo que antes, pero con columnas

    'LastRow y Col funcionan siempre y cuando no haya líneas ni columnas vacías entre la inicial y la final


    ' Podrías cambiar el Field:=10 por otra cosa si fuera variable o no estuviera siempre en el mismo sitio

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, Col)).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>#N/A" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd


    ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC10,[Contratos.xls]Feuil1!R2C1:R738C2,2,0)"
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    'Aquí copias la celda en la que acabas de hacer la fórmula
    ws.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Columns(9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Copy
    'Asumo que todo esto es en tu columna 10 y seleccionamos todas las celdas visibles en esa columna y pegamos como fórmulas
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 10), ws.Cells(LastRow, 10)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Perfecto, una gran solución. Muchas gracias por el aporte.